# How to mock an api to verify if it's rendering correctly with jest and fetch

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

After mutiple research, i never find a concrete example to help me understand this.

What i want to achieve : Mock the api and test if it's rendering correctly.

Can someone could give me a code example to see how to test this with jest concretely so i can apply this to all my other functions in my project, i really don't understand how to this.

Thank you for your help.

**REAL API from api folder**

```
export const searchTrack = search => {
  return fetch(
    `${url}/search/tracks?q=${encodeURIComponent(
      search
    )}&limit=250&media=music`,
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: Cookies.get("token")
      }
    }
  )
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(jsonFormat => {
      return jsonFormat.results;
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.error("fetch for search dont work");
    });
};
```

**addTracksPlaylist.vue method called**

```
  methods: {
    search() {
      if (this.term !== "") {
        this.results = [];
        this.searching = true;
        apiPlaylist
          .searchTrack(this.term)
          .then(res => {
            if (res.status != 401) {
              this.searching = false;
              this.results = res;
              this.noResults = this.results.length === 0;
            }
          })
          .catch(() => {
            this.$router.push("/login");
          });
      }
    }
  }
```

**I saw that everyone was creating a __mocks__ folder in the api folder so i created one with the api 
GET return**

```
    {
      wrapperType: "track",
      kind: "song",
      artistId: 461932,
      collectionId: 196480323,
      trackId: 196480329,
      artistName: "Europe",
      collectionName: "The Final Countdown",
      trackName: "The Final Countdown",
      collectionCensoredName: "The Final Countdown",
      trackCensoredName: "The Final Countdown",
      artistViewUrl: "https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/europe/id461932?uo=4",
      collectionViewUrl:
        "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/the-final-countdown/id196480323?i=196480329&uo=4",
      trackViewUrl:
        "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/the-final-countdown/id196480323?i=196480329&uo=4",
      previewUrl:
        "http://a1815.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/101/Music/70/f0/fd/mzm.hhpjhkpl.aac.p.m4a",
      artworkUrl30:
        "http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Music/fc/4c/f5/mzi.jpmevzoi.30x30-50.jpg",
      artworkUrl60:
        "http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Music/fc/4c/f5/mzi.jpmevzoi.60x60-50.jpg",
      artworkUrl100:
        "http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Music/fc/4c/f5/mzi.jpmevzoi.100x100-75.jpg",
      collectionPrice: 9.99,
      trackPrice: 1.29,
      releaseDate: "1988-09-16T07:00:00Z",
      collectionExplicitness: "notExplicit",
      trackExplicitness: "notExplicit",
      discCount: 1,
      discNumber: 1,
      trackCount: 13,
      trackNumber: 1,
      trackTimeMillis: 310333,
      country: "USA",
      currency: "USD",
      primaryGenreName: "Rock",
      radioStationUrl: "https://itunes.apple.com/station/idra.196480329"
    },
    {}
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to test your function by mocking the response from the call to `searchTrack` method, you can use jest mocks to easily achieve this.

The jest mock can be created with a simple `jest.fn()`.

You can provide your own implementation to the same using either of the below:

```
jest.fn(() => { //implementation goes here })

OR

jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => { //implementation goes here })
```

Since you need to mock out an API response, you should have a mock which returns a Promise.

So something like this should do your job:

```
jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(mockDataValue))
```

Jest also provides a shorthand for this via the `mockResolvedValue` function.

```
jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(data)
```

This also does the same. Also, there is the `mockRejectedValue` method if you want to test out the error scenario as well.

More information available at [Jest Mock API Reference](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api)